# Data not give back correctly with json.parse()

Tags: javascript, json

I am having issues about getting data when check date availability, the data gave back to me not correctly

Here is my code base:

```
searchFakeMonthlyAvailability(query: FormData): Promise<Results> {
    return new Promise<Results>((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            let srStr: string = JSON.stringify(searchMonthlyResults);
            let sr: Results = JSON.parse(srStr);
            console.log('srStr: ', srStr)
            console.log("sr: ", sr)
            sr.monthlyresults = sr.monthlyresults.filter(result => moment(result.date).toDate().getMonth() === moment(query.startDate).toDate().getMonth())
            resolve(sr);
        }, 1500);
    });
}
```

so when I `console.log(stStr)` this is what i got:

> {"filters":{"roomType":[{"value":"2BR","description":"2
> Bedroom","priority":800,"minimumPoints":650},{"value":"3BR","description":"3
> Bedroom","priority":900,"minimumPoints":800}],"views":[{"value":"GV","description":"Garden
> View","minimumPoints":650},{"value":"OS","description":"Ocean
> Side","minimumPoints":650},{"value":"OV","description":"Ocean
> View","minimumPoints":650}],"activities":[],"area":[{"name":"St. Kitts
> and Nevis","continent":"Caribbean","states":[{"name":"","cities":["St.
> Kitts"]}]}]},"results":[],"monthlyresults":[{"date":"20211120","minimumPoints":925},{"date":"20211117","minimumPoints":1050},{"date":"20211129","minimumPoints":750},{"date":"20211116","minimumPoints":1050},{"date":"20211111","minimumPoints":925},{"date":"20211101","minimumPoints":650},{"date":"20211127","minimumPoints":925},{"date":"20211108","minimumPoints":1050},{"date":"20211119","minimumPoints":1100},{"date":"20211107","minimumPoints":850},{"date":"20211118","minimumPoints":1500},{"date":"20211102","minimumPoints":650},{"date":"20211128","minimumPoints":750}],"dailyresults":[],"minimumNights":0,"maxOutMonth":"20220906"}

and when I do `console.log(sr)`: this is what I got:

> dailyresults: [] filters: activities: [] area: [{…}] roomType:
> Array(2) 0: {value: '2BR', description: '2 Bedroom', priority: 800,
> minimumPoints: 650} 1: {value: '3BR', description: '3 Bedroom',
> priority: 900, minimumPoints: 800} length: 2 [[Prototype]]: Array(0)
> views: Array(3) 0: {value: 'GV', description: 'Garden View',
> minimumPoints: 650} 1: {value: 'OS', description: 'Ocean Side',
> minimumPoints: 650} 2: {value: 'OV', description: 'Ocean View',
> minimumPoints: 650} length: 3 [[Prototype]]: Array(0) [[Prototype]]:
> Object maxOutMonth: "20220906" minimumNights: 0 monthlyresults: []
> monthlyunavailableresults: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}] results: []

my data missing monthlyresults. How can I fix this ?

Updated

Comment: looks like your filter() isn't returning anything, have you checked that date creation is happening as expected?

Comment: What's the value of `moment(query.startDate).toDate().getMonth()`?

Comment: BTW, doesn't moment.js have its own method to get the month? Why convert it to a date first?

Comment: @pilchard It did return value I just updated the code

Comment: The console has a live reference to the object. So when you replace `sr.monthlyresults` with the filtered array, that will change what you see in the console.

Comment: @Barmar value of `moment(query.startDate).toDate().getMonth()` is 3

Comment: All the dates in the JSON have month = 10. So none of the months match and the filtered array is empty. That's what you see in your console.log.